# Loop through Weekdays array with JavaScript and add a class for today's 'date'

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a static looking calendar and basically want to highlight the today's column.

I'm looping through the calendar rows, like so:

```
var weekdays = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
$('.calendar__row').each(function (index, value) {
    $(this).append(weekdays[index])
})
```

When it hits 'today' - I want to add a class to the 'calendar__row' - how would this be done?

I end up with:

```
<div class="calendar__row">Mon</div>
<div class="calendar__row">Tue</div>
<div class="calendar__row">Wed</div>...so on
```

I'd like to add a class on the day that we're on if that's possible! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) function which returns a number from 0 to 6 indicating the current day of the week (0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on):

```
var today = new Date().getDay();
```

and based on that check whether the index matches in your array and act accordingly with the class:

```
$('.calendar__row').each(function (index, value) {
    $(this).append(weekdays[index]);

    var today = new Date().getDay();    
    if (index == (today == 0 ? 6 : (today - 1))) {  
        $(this).addClass('today'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, something like this? if(today[date.getDay()]) {
   $(this).addClass('today')
  } - I can't quite figure the setup, any help appreciated :)

Comment: Be careful coz, getDay() will return 0 for Sunday, but your weekdays array starts at Monday so you need to account for that in your test: `if (index == (today == 0 ? 6 : (today - 1))) {  $(this).addClass('today'); }`.

Comment: Changed my array to begin with Sunday, so removed your '- 1' piece, but lovely, works great, thank you!